# How to open indexeddb database?

Tags: database, indexeddb, nw.js

I'm new to all of this.

I had created a offline game with nw.js. But the game could not load the data from the indexeddb. So, I wanted to open the database to see what is wrong, but I do not know what software to use to open the database/retrieve the values, could anyone please enlighten me or give me a direction? I just wanna know where should I be looking, I'm totally lost now..

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your browser. In Chrome, the devtools are pretty good: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage